# cake php in netbean is not working without internet connection

Tags: php, cakephp, netbeans

hello everyone I am new to php. I install netbeans in my system for work in ph and add cakephp in plugin. I create a project in php and did some practice when my computer was connected to the Internet.After some time I create a new project again in my netbeans without internet connection it ask me for the internet connection. Is it necessary to have a internet connection every time to u use netbeans? 
I am basically a .net developer But I never face this problem in Visual studio. But Why  in netbeans?

Please tell me PHP experts what is the solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Download cakephp zipped file to your local machine (ex:cakephp-2.4.4.zip)

2) tools > options > php > cakephp
browse add local cakephp zipped file ex: cakephp-2.4.4.zip

3) while creating a new project, in the step which you select "cakephp fremawork", click "unzip local file" option below (you will see the file name which you added before).